# Dealing with duplicates in the source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a query that looks like this in SQL server 2008:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (id, name)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM TABLE_1 t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_2)
```

The `NOT IN` deals with the case where I already hava a value in `TABLE_1`, but I get errors when there are duplicate values in `TABLE_2` that are not yet in `TABLE_1`. Is there a way to deal with this?

The problem is that my `TABLE_1` has a unique constraint on `id` but my `TABLE_2` does not, and this cannot be changed.

Comment: What is the result you want here? If `[name]` has different values for the 2 same ID's, which should be used?

Comment: TOP (1) would work, if there's a way to do this?

Comment: @Larnu Basically I dont care because If  `[id]` is duplicate it meanes there was an error and everythign else is duplicate so ill take any but just 1 of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding DISTINCT to the select to avoid the duplicate values?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (id, name)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name
FROM TABLE_1 t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_2)
```

Comment: I still get a duplicate error when using distinct

Comment: What does the constraint on?  id, name or both?

Comment: @Bob_K constraint is only on id

Comment: ok, so in t1 you have more than one row with the same id then?

Comment: @Bob_K yes and that is the problem, t1 has duplicates and t2 wont take them

Comment: @Chsir17  - the distinct would remove duplicate Id / name pairs.  You must have duplicates names with the same Id then.   Which do you want, the name or the ID?

Comment: @Chsir17 - it would seem that the IDs don't matter at all if they are mapped to multple name and you just want the new distinct name values.

I would alter Table_2 to auto-increment the Id column.
Then execute this:

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (name)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM TABLE_1 t1

That will give you a new set of distinct names with duplicates removed and new unique IDs.

To avoid duplicate names, you should create a new unique constraint on the name column in table_2 to avoid this happening again.

Comment: @Bob_K I only want to select a single ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174505/discussion-between-bob-k-and-chsir17).

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (id, name) 
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, (select top 1 name from TABLE_1 where id = t1.id) 
FROM TABLE_1 t1 
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_2)